# Is it possible to define a date format that adapts to changeable data?

Tags: iphone, ios, date, format, nsdateformatter

I need to find a date format which could adapt to the two following dates:

1. `2012-01-22T14:27:31.176+0000`
2. `2012-01-22T14:27:31+0000`

As you can see, the only difference is that date 2 does not have the fractional seconds.

The two date formats would be:

1. `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SZ`
2. `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ`

with the second one omitting **.S**.

Is it possible to make **.S** optional? Or do I have to keep using 2 different formats?

The problem lies in the fact that I'm getting the date from an API call, and sometimes it comes with the fractional seconds, other times without.

I guess I could detect the presence of the decimal place and use the two different date formats accordingly, but I was looking for a cleaner solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "lenient" property suggested by @JustSid in this case did not work.

Having not found a "cleaner" solution, I went back to my first one, which was detecting the presence of the decimal place and using the two different date formats accordingly.

```
NSRange textRange =[targetDate rangeOfString:@"."];

if(textRange.location == NSNotFound) {
    format = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ";
} else {
    format = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SZ";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `NSDateFormatter`'s `lenient` property to `YES` which allows the `NSDateFormatter` to take a guess on your input string. However, you should test this since it might give you some false positives.

Comment: I didn't know that, it might be useful. I'll give it a try, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the first thing could be to look at the actual length of the data. Not clean, but should work

Answer (score 0):

Could you test the length of the string and then use one of 2 different date formatters depending on the length?

Answer (score 0):

I would have two date formatters, and then choose the date formatter to use depending on wether there is a decimal place or not in your date string.

I dont think there is a format string that would make the decimal optional

Alternatively you could just use the format string with the fractional seconds, your dates without fractional seconds would just display with a .00 on the end, might look more consistent?